# Accessing network created by Internet Sharing

Tags: macbook-pro, network, macos, internet-sharing

I would like to be able to access services on devices that are connected to my shared network.

Basically I have set up network sharing such that when I connect via Thunderbolt-Ethernet I share the connection over wifi. In order to do this my mac (I guess) creates some virtual network for devices to be be issued an IP address on. So what I would like to be able to do is to bridge (??) this network so that I can access the devices on it.

More specifically I would like to be able to access a service on a specific port that a device on the share's network is hosting.

Is this possible? And if so how?

Comment: Please add your OS X system version to your question.

Comment: Ive added another tag is that enough?

Comment: yepp. additionally i need a drawing of your network ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my proxy settings. I had proxy setting configured which were not valid for the network my host machine was connected to. For some reason this was not an issue over HTTP but HTTPS refused connections...